# How to transfer files from S3 to Azure blob continously

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, command-prompt, windows-task-scheduler

I have one line script which copies files from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob. I need to schedule it in windows to run every 30 min...I scheduled as below:

```
schtasks /create /SC minute /MO 2 /tn "my task" /tr "\"C:\azcopy\script.bat"
```

Code in script.bat

```
azcopy cp "https://s3.amazonaws.com/testblobutopud/"   "https://blobtestutopus.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-10-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-07-31T15:08:13Z&st=2020-07-16T07:08:13Z&spr=XXX" --recursive
```

The code runs every 2 min...i can see the command.exe UI every 2min...But I couldn't see the output as expected.

I can't see files in Azure..But instead when i run `script.bat` individually i can see the output in Azure

Could anyone pls suggest any other method to copy the files from S3 to azure continously.

Comment: Please see if this link helps: https://bornsql.ca/blog/using-azcopy-with-batch-files-and-task-scheduler/

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Thanks for the reply. But its confusing!

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Could u pls help me